# Scrolling technique

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Does anyone know what this scrolling technique is called?  I would like to implement a similar solution.

[Example Site](http://editsquarterly.com)

Comment: You can simple show source and see it by yourself. It's JavaScript by jQuery.

Comment: Off ourse i can look at the source but that is not what I asked.  My question has been answered by Sven.  I was specifically looking for the nomenclature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a modified version of the so called "parallax scrolling", invented by some guy at Nike.

It's quite a little bit different but uses the same basics.